# Ember-CLI - triggering livereload while developing an addon

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-cli-addons

I'm developing an ember-cli addon and I'd like to know if it's possible to set up live reload to trigger whenever I make a change in my addon. As of now, I have to restart my server every time I make a change to my addon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Officially, the way to do this is to edit your index.js and add the following:

```
isDevelopingAddon: function() {
    return true;
},
```

This is documented here: http://www.ember-cli.com/extending/#link-to-addon-while-developing

This only works if you have used npm link to link your addon to your application.

Update: This may have been broken since ember-cli 0.2.7 https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/4289

Comment: So I've done all of that and I can use my addon in my app, but changing my addon still doesnt trigger the live reload.

Comment: Good find. I'll mark it as answered since you linked to a known issue thats more than likely a problem with watchman.

Comment: just to clarify the `index.js` file you want is the one at the TOP level of your addon project (same level as the package.json), not the one inside the `addon` directory